# Getting url tag value from Bluemix push notification

Tags: cordova, ibm-cloud, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobile-services, ibm-cloud-plugin

I need to pass the url along with the notification message using Bluemix Rest API. According to the docs

```
{"message": {
"alert": "Notification alert message","url":"test.test.com" }}
```

The above rest call should send the message and the url. But when i tried to parse the Json object from the notification there is no tag that sends the url.

[image]

```
 MFPPush.registerDevice(settings, success, failure);
 var notification = function(notif){
     alert (JSON.stringify(notif));

 };
 MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notification);
    }}
```

The above is the code that I am registering the notification from javascript using Cordova app.

The code below shows the AppDelegate code on iOS:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
```

didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

```
[[CDVMFPPush sharedInstance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
```

}

When i have put a log statement for userInfo in AppDelegate, the following log is displayed:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            "action-loc-key" = "<null>";
            body = test;
        };
    };
    payload = "{\"nid\":\"5a379af\",\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}";
    url = URL;
}
```

Its getting displayed in the dictionary. But how to get the url value from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the app in Xcode and go to `CDVMFPPush.swift` file and locate the `func didReceiveRemoteNotification(notification: NSDictionary?)`

Add the following line inside the above function

`notif["url"] = notification?.valueForKey("url")`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

@Rahul you have to add `notif["url"] = notification?.valueForKey("url")`  inside the `func didReceiveRemoteNotification(notification: NSDictionary?) {}` method to display in the notification popup.

Comment: I think u mistook that I am not able to get the info from the dictionary. But the issue here is that I am not able to get the key value pair of url from notification itself.